# Error in MATLAB GUI execution

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am trying to run this GUI code:

```
WeatherMonitor_1;
set(handles.text3,'String',V_PV1); 
set(handles.text4,'String',I_PV1);
```

But I am getting this error:

> error using matlab.ui.Figure/set There is no String property on the Figure class.
>
> Error in PV_Test1_GUI>pushbutton1_Callback (line 84) set(handles.text4,'String',I_PV1);
>
> Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95) feval(varargin{:});
>
> Error in PV_Test1_GUI (line 42) gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>
> Error in @(hObject,eventdata)PV_Test1_GUI('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> Error while evaluating UIControl Callback

The first string command is getting executed, but not the second one.

Comment: what do you get when you do: get(handles.text4,'style')?

Comment: At some point you have stored the handle to a figure window as `handles.text4` and overwritten the handle of your edit box. Or incorrectly defined it in the first place.